# AutoCompleteBox in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a Silverlight 3 project I am trying to convert to Silverlight 4. I use the autocompletebox. I cannot find the correct namespace/reference for this in Silverlight 4. Has it moved? What reference do I need? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Its in the `System.Windows.Controls.Input.dll` in the namespace `System.Windows.Controls`.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.autocompletebox(v=vs.95).aspx)

This has not changed from 3 to 4.